# How to reset form radio buttons to unchecked in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made 4 radio buttons for 1 question. I have made 2 buttons submit and clear input. When I submit the form after clicking on clear input it does not clear the checked buttons to unchecked how can I do that using `reset` 
function ?

contactform.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        age:'',
        gender:'',
        health:'',
        name:'',
        email:'',
        info:'',
        fitness:''
    };
  } 

setAge(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    this.setState({
        age:checkedValue
    })
  }

setGender(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    this.setState({
        gender:checkedValue
    })
  }

  onChangeTextBoxGender(event){
  this.setState({gender: event.target.value})
  }

 savedata(age, gender, health, name, email, info, fitness){
        let newcontent = contentref.push();
        newcontent.set({
            age:this.state.age,
            gender:this.state.gender,
            health:this.state.health,
            name:this.state.name,
            email:this.state.email,
            info:this.state.info,
            fitness:this.state.fitness
        });
  }

  reset(){
    this.setState({
      age:'',
      gender:''
    })
  }

 render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <div id="center">
          <form>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <h3>[Test]Contact us Survey Form</h3>  
                </div>
              </div>

            <div id="agegroup" >
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <h4>What is your age group?</h4>  
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>=25 yrs')}/> >=25 yrs</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="age"  onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'26-35 yrs')}/> 26-35 yrs</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'36-50 yrs')}/> 36-50 yrs</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>50 yrs')}/> >50 yrs</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div id="gender">
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <h4>What is your gender?</h4>  
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Female')}/> Female</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Male')}/> Male</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Prefer not to say')}/> Prefer not to say</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,-1)}/>Other</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-inline" id="other1" onChange={this.onChangeTextBoxGender.bind(this)}/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick={this.savedata.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Clear input</button>

          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a checked attribute for you radio button. Change

```
<label>
  <input 
    type="radio" 
    name="age" 
    onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>=25 yrs')} /> 
  {' '}      
  >=25 yrs
</label>
```

to

```
<label>
  <input 
    type="radio" 
    name="age" 
    checked={(this.state.age == '>=25 yrs')} 
    onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>=25 yrs')}/> 
  >=25 yrs
</label>
```

Comment: How can I handle the text area if the user checks `other` radio button

Comment: So you can use it like : checked={(this.state.age == '>=25 yrs')} or for other checked={(this.state.age == -1)}

Comment: Your answer does not work because whenever I click on any radio button only the last radio button gets checked.

Comment: Should it be `checked={this.state.age}` instead of `checked={(this.state.age)}`

Comment: checked attribute is boolean type so you can use it like checked={(this.state.age == '>=25 yrs')}

Comment: I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can control what is selected using the state, below find and example (btw, it is not a good practice generate functions inside the render function because it will cause unnecessary rerenders)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue : ''
  }

  optionSelected = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({
      selectedValue : e.target.value
    })
  }

  reset = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue : ''
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { selectedValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
         <input 
            type="radio" 
            name="age" value="A" 
            onChange={this.optionSelected}
            checked={selectedValue === 'A'}/> A
        </div>
        <div>
         <input 
            type="radio" 
            name="age" 
            value="B" 
            onChange={this.optionSelected}
            checked={selectedValue === 'B'}/> B
        </div>
        <div>
         <input 
            type="radio" 
            name="age" 
            value="C" 
            onChange={this.optionSelected}
            checked={selectedValue === 'C'}/> C
        </div>

        <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/wavusilefa/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering a onChange handler, updating the `state` correctly, but you aren't actually controlling the components with this data. Here's an in-depth guide from react about [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), and the recommended approach, [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) in Forms.

In your component, you need to manually set the props `checked` of each radio input based on the value of `this.state`.
For example:

```js
render() {
  // here you extract the data from the state
  const age = this.state.age
  const gender = this.state.gender
  ...
  <div className="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Female')} checked={gender === 'Female'}/> Female</label>
  </div>
  ... // and set checked for every input, using the age for the age radio buttons
 }
```

Thus, controlling the components like that, when you call `reset`, all inputs'll have the `checked` props set to false, and will get unmarked.

Comment: Ok got it but how can I clear text inside input box if user checks `other` radio buttton see 2nd screenshot.

Comment: You'll need another state for that, maybe another key in the state like `ageText`, you name it. And in the `reset`, you set it to '' like the others. Of course, it will need a separate handler for it too.

Comment: @stonerock First you need to set the value of the text input into whatever state is being set onChange then clear/reset this state to empty every time you want to clear the text inside the input box. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @PaulUpendo Yes I got it.

Comment: @stonerock, all correct with PaulUpendo comment, just remember to take your time to learn the full concept of controlling components in React.

Comment: @stonerock from what I see this will cause a bug, because the two types of input are sharing the same data, you need to separate them, create another key on state, like `ageText`, change the `onChangeTextBoxGender` handler to change this key on state, and pass it as props in the component, writing `value={this.state.ageText}`.

Comment: @rodgobbi Everything works fine but as you said there is bug in my input field. I will now add new state variable which will work out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In ReactJS:

`inputs` can be [`controlled`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) via their `value` / `checked` `props`.

These `props` are typically managed via `this.state`.

The alternative to [`controlled components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) is [`uncontrolled components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

See below for a practical example of how to dynamically construct a `radio` `form` of `controlled components` based on an `Array` of `Sections`.

```js
// Sections.
const sections = [
  {
    id: 'age',
    name: 'Age',
    options: [
      '20 - 30',
      '30 - 40',
      'Other'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'gender',
    name: 'Gender',
    options: [
      'Male',
      'Female',
      'Other'
    ] 
   }
]

// Radio Box
class RadioBox extends React.Component {

  // Constructor.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.initialState = sections.reduce((state, section) => ({...state, [section.id]: false}), {})
    this.state = this.initialState
  }

  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
      {sections.map((section, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <span>{section.name}</span>
          <ul>
            {section.options.map((option, index) => this.option(section.id, option, index))}
          </ul>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({[section.id]: false})}>Reset {section.name}</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button>Submit</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({...this.initialState})}>Clear form</button>
    </form>
  )
  
  // Submit.
  submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('Data:', this.state)
  }

  // Option.
  option = (id, option, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <label>{option}</label> <input type="radio" checked={this.state[id] == option} onChange={(event) => event.target.checked && this.setState({[id]: option})}/>
    </li>
  )
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<RadioBox/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use simple jquery selectors to select the value you want to clear, so your reset function would do something like this:

`$('input[name="age"]').attr('checked', false);`

Comment: @Anel Salem Yes I know how to do it with jquery but using jquery with ReactJs is bad practice. Can you tell me how to do the same thing in ReactJS ?

Comment: Hey @stonerock, sorry for the delay, why not create a state-based attribute that can be toggled onClick to set the checked attribute to true or false based on whether the button was clicked or not. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> You can add `checked` property inside your input tag

```
<input checked={your condition paste here} />
```

Ex:

```
<Input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked={this.state.gender === "male"} />
```